# How to have Zero To Many relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a class called `Member` that has a few `@OneToMany` relationships with other classes. I can insert only one `Member` with empty `OneToMany` relationships. Upon inserting the second `Member` I receive following exception.

```
ERROR: Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_7pn834d04yft1rkvpqf0viuyc'
```

**Code**

```
@Entity
public class Member {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend")
    private Set<Friendship> friends;
    ....
```

To insert `Member`, I am adding **empty set of friends** to it. I suspect this and suppose need to have `ZeroToMany` relationship but could not find its annotation in [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html).

**Update**

```
Member member = new Member(email, new HashSet<Friendship>());
```

Constructor

```
public Member(String email, Set<Friendship> friends) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
        this.friends = friends;
    }
```

toString

```
 member:Member [email=jack.moore1@outlook.com , friends=[]]
```

console

```
insert 
        into
            Member
            (username) 
        values
            (?)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no ZeroToMany relationship. That doesn't exist and doesn't have sense. You can't connect 0 entities with many entities. 
You should use @OneToMany relationship here, and you should initialize friends collection

```
private Set<Friendship> friends = new HashSet<Friendship>();
```

if you didn't do that in some constructor which is not shown here.

I would suggest to turn on show_sql hibernate property so you can have more details about the problem.

Comment: What I meant is to initialize somewhere inside the body of Member entity, e.g. constructor or within friends definition directly. You don't have that, but you create it somewhere in your code and you assign values through your constructor Member(String email, Set<Friendship> friends). However, Hibernate will use default constructore Member() when you read entitty from database, and it will try to add friends into nonexisting collection